# How to redirect user into mobile website?

Tags: php, htaccess, javascript

Hi how to redirect the user into mobile site when the user accessing from mobile. Say example i have site called www.mysite.com. Now, a person accessing a website from mobile it should redirect to www.mysite.com/mobile or www.m.mysite.com.

I put some research in google that we can redirect using javascript to get the user agent(browser)

```
if(mobile browser) {
  //redirect to www.mysite.com/mobile
} else if(normal browser) {
  //redirect to www.mysite.com
}

or using screen resolution

if(screen resolution < 800 ) {
  //redirect to www.mysite.com/mobile
} else if(screen resolution > 800) {
  //redirect to www.mysite.com
}
```

I think It will not work If it is the case of javascript disable.

Can we do this using .htaccess or php stuff?

Is there any standard mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use media queries for css

in you css put

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
... css here
}
```

the max-device-width should be the width of the mobile device you want to detect.

on the other hand u can use useragent

in javascript

```
var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);

if(isMobile) {
   // User-Agent is IPhone, IPod, IPad, Android or BlackBerry
}
```

to check the specific user-agent string

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/)) {
   // The User-Agent is iPhone
}
```

in php this is hwo you do this

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
}
```

check first the useragent of the device

the give the condition

```
if(preg_match('/^Mozilla\/.*?Gecko/i',$agent)){
print "Firefox user.";
// process here for firefox browser
}
```

in the pregmatch.. you can put into condition 'iPhone','Andriod' etc

Comment: javascript is not a trusted one, it will not work if it is the case of javascript disabled in mobile browser agent.

Comment: edited my post so that u can use PHP

Comment: Note that on Opera (Android), the UA string does not contain the "Android" sub-string.